# Delphi TWebBrowser keep getting CloudFare page

Tags: delphi, twebbrowser

When I use MS Edge, Firefox or Opera to access Cloudfare-protected webpages, it shows the page correctly.  However, using `TWebBrowser` it always shows the Cloudfare captcha page first.

How do I configure Delphi `TWebBrowser` to act like a "real" web browser which does not invite the Cloudfare page?

Note that this is occasional access to the page, and yet it triggered the cloudfare when the other browsers do not trigger at that same point in time.

Comment: Did you had a look at [understanding CloudFlare captchas and challenge passage](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170136-Understanding-Cloudflare-Captchas-and-Challenge-Passage)?

Comment: May be you don't handle cookies correctly? They surely must persists.

Comment: Did you try with IE?

Comment: On the contrary: try again with Edge, Firefox and Opera after **completely deleting** all of your cookies (and permanent storage). Just using `TWebBrowser` doesn't equal to using a complete web browser software.

Comment: @fpiette  thanks for link.  I had a look.  I don't think I have anything listed that would trigger a Captcha - eg, a suspicious ip address or actions.  as this would have triggered captcha in Edge, Firefox etc.   What I'm suspecting is that my TWebbrowser is not behaving as a full web browser software, ie, handling cookies?    Is there a way to make TWebbrowser behave like a full web browser?

Comment: @fpiette  How do I handle the cookies correctly in TWebBrowser? I'm new to it.  Is there a setting that says let TWebBrowser handle it automatically?  if not, how do I handle it manually? any sample code?

Comment: @Olivier - yes, just tried with IE.  IE also returns correct data with no cloudfare page.

Comment: @AmigoJack How do I let TWebBrowser behave sufficiently as a browser such as cookies so it will not trigger the cloudfare page?  any links or examples?

Comment: Which Delphi version are you using?

Comment: @fpiette 10.4.1 - I can use either vcl or firemonkey framework depending on which one works.

Comment: That TWebBrowser is based on Internet Explorer. Try accessing the same site with Internet Explorer, the captcha will surely pops up the first time. Then try with your program. BTW: Internet Explorer is deprecated by Microsoft and replaced by Edge. In newer Delphi versions, there is a new component based on Edge.

Comment: @fpiette I tried using IE but captcha doesn't pop up at all.  then I use TWebBrowser it pops up.

Comment: In your app, when the captcha is shown and you correctly fill it, does it appears the next run?

Comment: Do you have a link I can play with to reproduce your issue?

Comment: i would recommend to use a sniffer. Often its the additional active Content thats used to make sure your a "normal User" not any kind of bot/Scrapper. (Telerik fiddler or Wireshark) Compare a working Browser call versus TWebBrowser.  (alot of text i reccomend beyond compare or kdiff)

Comment: @fpiette for some websites, when captcha is shown the webpage does appear.  for some such as https://www.udemy.com it just shows an error message that their servers are busy without giving a chance to do captcha.

Comment: @Quelltextknecht how would i use a sniffer to solve the issue? for example, how do u tackle a website like https://www.udemy.com  that gives an error when using a TWebBrowser that doesn't even give me a chance to do a captcha?

Comment: I almost always get on TWebBrowser "an error has occurred in the script on this page" "Do you want to continue running scripts on this page"
- how do I suppress such errors on TWebBrowser and either give automatic Yes or No.

Comment: The sniffer could be used to compare the sequence of requests/responses sent by IE and by your application. Finding the differences could tell what the problem is.

Comment: To not display javascript errors, set the `silent` property to `true`.

Comment: I can reproduce your issue...

Comment: @fpiette I used the silent property - solved the error problem. Thanks!

Comment: @fpiette "I can reproduce your issue..." - do you mean you can reproduce the "udemy" issue?

Comment: Exactly. I see the same as you do.

Comment: @fpiette any way to resolve the udemy error issue? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Not an real answer but some things i encountered with TWebBrowser on the "real" Internet.

The Sites i encountered needed different things.

- Some needed a Header Information with specific Browsers.
- Executing java script to read your system envronment for language (geoblocking)
- Some need cookies obtained through cross site Scripting (Fraud protection)
- and many other Things for various reasons.

So, for your Target Website you can sniff where your call beginns to differ from a working Browser. And then trying to reproduce the functionality for Your Application.

What you encounter is not a TWebBrowser Problem in itself. It is Browser Funtionality used to have Features like Geoblocking, Addblock detection or whatever. So you need to implement the missing Parts: Cookie Storage and/or Java Script.

The downside is: you only find one missing Part after the other. So when you start you dont know if you will hit a dead end. Doing "real Internet Sites" with TWebBrowser (based on IE 5.5) was not easy and that was around 2005 ... in the early easy days...

Optional: If you have an Invitation from the Site owner through an Api Key (or something similar for Authentification) it should work with the TWebBrowser. If all the "Protection" is not needed it worked on almost everyting.

I never found a solid working Solution, but changing the Header to be IE5.5, enabling the newer Mode(non legacy?) and Cookies + Script helped.

If possible try it with the new Edge Component or an embedded Chrome / Firefox / Opera.

In the End we used a microsoft IE COM Component and not the Delphi Component. But even then, not everything was working.